# ArrayList mixing up indexes?

Tags: java, libgdx

Working title.

I'm warming up to libgdx and I'm trying to remove objects from an ArrayList when pressed/touched. The Objects are rectangles and about 70% of them get removed, the other 30% just stays on screen or gets removed when I press on another indexes position, its like its mixing up indexes.

Adding Enemy:

```
    public void updateEnemy(float dt){
    enemyTimer += dt;
    if(enemyTimer > 3){
        enemyArrayList.add(new Enemy(enemyImg.getWidth(), enemyImg.getHeight()));
        enemyTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

Drawing enemy:

```
    public void drawEnemy(float dt){
    for(int i = 0; i < enemyArrayList.size(); i++){
        batch.draw(enemyImg, enemyArrayList.get(i).getX(), enemyArrayList.get(i).getY());           
    }       
}
```

Setting bounds for enemy:

```
    public void setBounds(int width, int height){
        bounds.set(position.x, position.y, position.x + width, position.y + height);
    }
```

Checking for touch on enemy:

```
    @Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    for(int i = 0; i < screen.getEnemyArray().size(); i++){
        if(screen.getEnemyArray().size() > 0){
            System.out.print(screenX + " - " + screenY + ", ");
            if(screen.getEnemyArray().get(i).getBounds().contains(screenX, screenY)){
                screen.getEnemyArray().remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can't see where Im going wrong, any suggestions is appriciated.

Comment: This appears to be a "debug my code" question. Further, it's not strictly game development related.

Comment: Where in this question do I ask anyone to write me any code or to debyg my code? Only reason I post my code is to show what I've alrdy tried

Comment: I'm not sure how they could answer without doing that. You actually don't ask a question at all. That includes not asking specifically for someone to debug your code, however I think this is where you imply that: "*I can't see where I'm going wrong, any suggestions is appreciated*".

Comment: Fair enough, didnt mean it like that tho. But ye,, poorly frased question

Comment: Maybe, you should consider more on what you're tagging, @Max. For instance, Game Development talks about idea and concept on how to make the game. You can also provide with minimal codes related to physics and game-related library like LibGDX for example. However, if you're asking more about errors and bugs, I should suggest go to *Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in general, if you're going to remove items from an ArrayList, you're going to skip over stuff with the pattern.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    if (something)
        list.remove(i);
```

You should get better results iterating backwards while removing so the indices don't shift, or simply decrementing 'i' when you delete:

```
for (int i=list.size()-1; i>=0; i--) ....
//or
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if (something) { 
       list.remove(i);
       i--; 
    }
}
```

However, you may later run into issues because you're removing enemies while in the middle of your game logic. Often we have to use a two-step removal process, where we mark an enemy 'deleted' and then at the end of the frame when everything is done, we can remove them from the list.

Comment: Moving the iterator mid loop can get messy. Especially if you happen to then set i to a value that is not an index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to iterate over an array and remove items from it at the same time. I am surprised you didn't get a `concurrentmodificationexception` thrown by Java. There are a few tricks you can do with the iterator, like the one Jimmy mentioned. However, they are unsafe and can lead to unexpected results.

Libgdx has a few collection classes along with ArrayList that you can use.
Detials here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Collections

**Snapshot Array**
Has .begin() and .end() functions that allow you modify an array with an iterator. Any modifications after .begin() are not applied until .end() is called. Internal backing array is copied, and you continue to iterate over the old array once .begin() is called. Require the iterator to be constructed in a particular way. (.size must be called)

**DelayedRemovalArray**
Similar with SnapShot Array, but works slightly differently. Removal is actually just delayed until .end() is called.

You can also creates an ArrayList call toBeRemoved. Any items needed to be removed are added this array. Then iterate over toBeRemoved and remove items in it from the first ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Snapshot array sounds interesting, but I'm having trouble finding examples of people using it, should I just do like this? `SnapshotArray enemyArray = new SnapshotArray();
// ...
Object[] items = enemyArray.begin();
for (int i = 0, n = enemyArray.size; i &lt; n; i++) {
        //remove from array here
}
array.end();`

How would i actually remove something from this type of array? what line of code would remove an index?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an Iterator to do the job:

```
Iterator<Enemy> it = enemyArrayList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
   Enemy e = it.next();
   if (something)
   {
      it.remove();
   }
}
```